# Getting error: "No mailbox with such guid." when accessing shared mailbox folder

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Hello i'm using following code to access shared mailbox using EWS:

```
            var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppSettingsHelper.GetValue<string>($"DataMailBoxLogin"), AppSettingsHelper.GetValue<string>($"DataMailBoxPassword")),
                Url = new Uri(AppSettingsHelper.GetValue<string>($"DataMailBoxExchangeApi"))
            };

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            var sharedMailbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, AppSettingsHelper.GetValue<string>($"DataMailBoxRespondEmail"));
            var loFolder = Folder.Bind(service, sharedMailbox);


            var results = service.FindItems(loFolder.Id, Querystring, new ItemView(10));
```

I'm getting following error on this line: var loFolder = Folder.Bind(service, sharedMailbox);

> ERROR 10-01-2020 11:14:01
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: No
>   mailbox with such guid.    v
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
>   v
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Responses\ServiceResponse.cs:řádek
>   277    v
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   v
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:řádek
>   169    v
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder(FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet) v
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:řádek
>   278    v
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId
>   folderId, PropertySet propertySet) v
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:řádek
>   295    v
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(ExchangeService
>   service, FolderId id) v
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ServiceObjects\Folders\Folder.cs:řádek
>   55    v
>   Millennium.Pgrlf.WindowsServices.DataMailbox.DataMailBox.Scheduling.PushInfoToCrmJob.d__4.MoveNext()
>   93 ServiceName: (null) AssemnlyVersion: 1.0.0.0
>   C:\registers\ReferencProjects\Millennium.Pgrlf.AppCore\Log4Net\Loggers\LogerBase.cs
>   Millennium.Pgrlf.WindowsServices.exe 
>   Millennium.Pgrlf.AppCore.Log4Net.Loggers.LogerBase.Error(C:\registers\ReferencProjects\Millennium.Pgrlf.AppCore\Log4Net\Loggers\LogerBase.cs:93)
>   Millennium.Pgrlf.WindowsServices.DataMailbox.AppLogger Error 14960
>   Millennium.Pgrlf.AppCore.Log4Net.Loggers.LogerBase xxx\xxx

Account has a full privileges to mailbox and has license assigned. We tried to set msExchMailboxGuid property to null on that account, but it didn't help.
I tried to connect through https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx, but the same problem.
I tried to connect to my personal mailbox too, without success.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that this line `sharedMailbox` reference to a correct folder?

Comment: I'm sure, that it reference to correct mailbox. Not sure about folder, but this "WellKnownFolderName.Inbox", looks like correct reference to folder.